# SetState doesn't work with with data from server

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

Hi I'm programming a page with React hooks and I'm trying to set the data I get from the server in to the state. SOmehow it doesnt work. I get the data from the server, but i cant map it to the state. Any Ideas what the problem could be?

```
const [workouts, setWorkouts] = React.useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
        apiGet(fitnessaryEndPoints.workouts.getAllWorkouts)
            .then(
                response => {
                    setWorkouts([...workouts, response.data])
                    console.log(response)
                    console.log(workouts)

                }
            ).catch(
            error => {
                console.log(error)
            }
        )
    }, [])
```

[data from Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPbri.png)

Comment: did you try `setWorkouts([...workouts, ...response.data])`?

Comment: @UzairRiaz Yep I did, it didn't work either

Comment: I can merge the state and the data in a variabvle but i cant set that variable to the state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`setWorkouts` is async method**, so you will not get updated data right below it.

```
setWorkouts([...workouts, response.data])
console.log(workouts) //<--- this will not reflect the updated data
```

Else your code is good, it will be reflected in DOM if you are looping and showing it

---

**Run the below code snippet and check HTML and console both, that will clear the flow.**

```js
const { useState , useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {

  const [users,setUsers] = useState(['Vivek' , 'Darsh']);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setUsers([...users, "Vivan" , "Darshita"]);
      console.log(users);
    },2000);
  },[]);

  return (
    <div>
      { users.map(user => <p>{user}</p>) }
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```