# How to split arrays inside object and push to seperate state?

Tags: reactjs

Hopefully, I will be able to explain what I am trying to do here. I am using WordPress as my API and fetching data using CRA.

I have an object with 2 different arrays when I console log my data.

Which returns: `{consult_business: Array(2), consult_strategy: Array(2)}`

I have a state:

```
const [consult, setConsult] = useState({
    consult_business: [],
    consult_strategy: []
});
```

Now, what I am trying to do on load, push these 2 Arrays inside a separate array and push them inside the consulting state. This way I would be able to map through the values based on the dropdown selection value.

I would like to do this wit useEffect.

How can I do that?

Comment: It looks like you could simply `setConsult(data)` since it already has the same object shape. If you shared a bit more I may be able to confirm that, but I stand by my assessment. Or are you asking how/when/where to go about fetching the data?

Comment: @DrewReese the "data" returns an object with 2 different arrays. I need to split those 2 arrays inside separate arrays instead of everything inside one object.

Comment: Your state is a single object with two properties that are arrays, which matches exactly the response data shape you shared. What needs to be split?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do it :

As your data `{consult_business: Array(2), consult_strategy: Array(2)}` matches with state structure you can directly set it, as shown below

```
useEffect(() => {

   // first make API call and get details

   setConsult(your_data); // <-- then set those details via this

},[]); //<--- [] means it will execute useEffect only once , as you need on load
```

---

You can access those values via,

```
consult.consult_business // <--- Will provide first array
consult.consult_strategy // <--- Will provide you second array
```

if you want to join both arrays, you can do this :

```
[...consult.consult_business , ...consult.consult_strategy]
```

Comment: I am trying to separate these 2 arrays inside the object and push the to different arrays inside the default state.

Comment: One more thing when i use the [] in useEffect it returns false and nothing on console log.

Comment: @NinoMerdzanovic, Dont depend on console.log , its due to async behavior , for that you can check , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61716831/setstate-doesnt-work-with-with-data-from-server/61717062#61717062

Comment: @NinoMerdzanovic, if you like the above demo, you can also upvote that once :)

Answer (score 0):

Given state

```
const [consult, setConsult] = useState({
  consult_business: [],
  consult_strategy: []
});
```

And a response data shape that matches exactly the state shape (*object with same keys and value types*)

```
{consult_business: Array(2), consult_strategy: Array(2)}
```

The pattern would be

```
useEffect(() => {
  // fetch data
  setConsult(data);
}, []); // <-- empty dependency array to run effect once on component mount
```